# OpenAM IdP initiated SSO url and SP initiated SSO url

Tags: openam

I have configured OpenAM IdP and SP. I am struggling with IdP initiated SSO URL and SP initiated SSO URL. I am using below format for IdP initiated SSO URL. But I am getting error `service provider ID is null`.

http://testtestidam.com:8080/openam/idpssoinit?metaAlias=/realm1/idp&spEntityid=http://localhost:8080/openam&binding=http-post.

Could anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change the parameter name `spEntityid` to `spEntityID`.

Comment: And binding to HTTP-POST

Comment: I tried with spEntityID and binding=HTTP-POST. Now i am getting the error "HTTP Status 400 - Error processing AuthnRequest. Error retrieving meta data."  description:The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. Message:Error processing AuthnRequest. Error retrieving meta data.

Comment: You can see a stacktrace of the error in `/openam/debug/Federation`.

Comment: Error retrieving metadata message will most likely mean that the metaAlias you defined in the request doesn't actually exist in the deployment.